# $routeParams undefined in factory angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, routeparams

I have a factory inside angularjs module. This factory return a variable that its used in different controllers. In this factory I am use $routeParams but return undefined even when the param is in url.

My code

```
.factory("tenant", function ($routeParams) {
    let tenant = { id: 'example.com' };

    // set selected tenant if a tenant param is passed
    if ($routeParams.tenant) {
        tenant.id = $routeParams.tenant;
    }

    return tenant;
})
```

The url: https://.....?tenant=example

but $routeParams.tenant is undefined

route config:

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {template: '<home></home>'})

        .when('/datasets', {template: '<datasets></datasets>'})
        .when('/new-dataset', {template: '<new-dataset></new-dataset>'})
        .when('/explore', {template: '<explore></explore>'})

        .when('/new-version', {template: '<new-version></new-version>'})

        .when('/projects', {template: '<projects></projects>'})
        .when('/new-project', {template: '<new-project></new-project>'})
        .when('/compare', {template: '<compare-project></compare-project>'})

        .when('/new-analysis', {template: '<new-analysis></new-analysis>'})
        .when('/view-analysis', {template: '<view-analysis></view-analysis>'})

        .when('/models', {template: '<models></models>'})
        .when('/predict', {template: '<predict></predict>'})
        .when('/new-model', {template: '<new-model></new-model>'})
        .when('/view-model', {template: '<view-model></view-model>'})

        .when('/new-workitem', {template: '<new-workitem></new-workitem>'})
        .when('/edit-workitem', {template: '<edit-workitem></edit-workitem>'})
        .when('/workitems', {template: '<workitems></workitems>'});

    // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
    // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

The problem is in  /

Comment: Can you post your router config function with the states you've defined?

Comment: ok add route config in the post

Comment: The `tenant` route param will only be added to the `$routeParams` if the `tenant` is defined in the route, e.g. `.when('/models/:tenant')`. If you don't want to define it in every route, you can do `var tenant = $location.search().tenant;`

Comment: Thank. Exactly, I resolved with $location